# Get name of the View containing Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a custom Tag Helper which needs to know the name or filename of the View that contains the Tag Helper.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (for asp.net core)

```
 public static String Path(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
       => ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView)htmlHelper.ViewContext.View).Path;
```